# PHP json_decode return null when delling with json array

Tags: php, json

**i have this json result**

```
 [{"counter":"542"}]
or 
    [{"counter":"542"},{"counter":"43"}]
```

and i have the following code

```
$address = "http://localhost/restauranttheme/syncAndroid/getCounterGenerator4Android.php";
$string = file_get_contents($address);
$json_a = json_decode($string );
```

but i am getting null result `$json_a == null`

So what is the problem?

Comment: can you please post the contents of http://localhost/restauranttheme/syncAndroid/getCounterGenerator4Android.php

Comment: how are you populating `$json_a`. use `print_r` OR `var_dump`.

Comment: What about doing some error checking? Does the content of the url get loaded at all into `$string`?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($string);`?

Comment: could you show method which called from `getCounterGenerator4Android.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have named the variable $json_a I guess you're expecting an array. If so you may be trying to use an object as an array, which wont work too well. Add a second param (true) to json_decode to return an array instead of an object.

```
$string = '[{"counter":"542"},{"counter":"43"}]';
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
// array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["counter"]=> string(3) "542" } [1]=> array(1) { ["counter"]=> string(2) "43" } }
```

Comment: Doesn't explain why he's getting null though. The problem is probably in the `file_get_contents` call.

Comment: i put "true" parameter , but it did not work too :(
it always return null !!